# how to find a specific column in 2d array using divide and conquer

Tags: arrays, algorithm, divide-and-conquer

I am trying to solve a divide and conquer problem where I have a 2d boolean array filled with true and false. I am trying to find a specific column where it's only true. There is also another way to find this column is to find a row where it contains only 1 true index and the rest is false. I must find solution less than O(N^2)

sample of 2d array:

```
F F T F
F T T T
F F T T
T F T F
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible, unless the array has some additional constraints. If you are constructing the array yourself, then you can probably get the answer already then.

Comment: there is a constraint , if i find the row which has only 1 true element in the array the index of this 1 true would be the same as the coulmn with all true .

Comment: I see, then it is probably possible to do it in O(n).

Comment: Posted O(n) solution and upvoted the question, it is a nice exercise.

Comment: One way on doing this: Pick any row as a driving row. It will have the correct column in it obviously. Scan this row looking for elements that are set ('T'). When you find one then scan that column up and down looking for 'F'. If you find one then abort that column. Otherwise you have found the correct column (end). :)   Continue the scan down the  'driving  row' repeating the scan until you find the correct column.  I suspect it will be quite quick normally. The worse case is horrid. ;-/

Comment: You can use a recursive algorithm for this. Think of doing binary searches on the columns. I think you could run multiple threads in parallel if you wish. It is an interesting problem. see quicksort / binary search for implementations.

Comment: imo, The addition of the line of false apart from the true column isn't as useful as it first appears. If you work out pathological test cases then searching for that one row can be very expensive. I would go with the divide and conquer approach as mentioned already in the question requirements. see Quicksort and binary search.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an O(n) solution, it is possible if we know that at least one row only contains a single true value and therefore this is the column we are looking for.

1. Add each column index to a hash set
2. For each row go through the set using an iterator and do the following:

   1. If you encounter a false value for that column index, remove it from the set.
   2. If you encounter a true value, set a boolean value to true, so that you know it is the first encounter of a true value, if you already encountered a true value continue with the next row

The single value remaining in the set is the solution.

This is O(n) because 1. is O(n) and 2. is O(n) too, so overall it is O(n) + O(n) = O(n). 2. is O(n) because for each row you look at a maximum of 2 true values (2 is a constant) and if you encounter a false value then you won't look at that column again.

I realised now that linked lists are even more suitable for this task than hash sets. An implementation could look like this (I implemented the list myself for educational purposes):

```
public class Node {
    public int value;
    public Node next;
    public Node(int value, Node prev) {
        this.value = value;
        if (prev != null)
            prev.next = this;
    }
}
```

```
public int getTrueColumn(boolean[][] array) {
    Node head = new Node(0, null);
    Node current = head;
    for (int i = 1; i < array[0].length; i++)
        current = new Node(i, current);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        boolean encounteredTrue = false;
        current = head;
        Node prev = null;
        while (current != null) {
            if (array[i][current.value]) {
                if (encounteredTrue)
                    break;
                encounteredTrue = true;
                prev = current;
            } else {
                if (prev == null)
                    head = current.next;
                else
                    prev.next = current.next;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
    return head.value;   
}
```

Comment: I'd personally always prefer to test my code before posting!

Comment: @RoxcH You cannot take a random generator. There are two conditions that have to be fulfilled: 1. There must be a column where all values are true, 2. There must be a row where all values except one are false. This is stated in the question.

Comment: Well i must confess that i had overlooked that weird constrain… I'll take my posts back!